# How to export multiple arrays from IronPython to CSV

Tags: python, csv, ironpython

I'm trying to export `Two float arrays` into a `CSV` file using IronPython, here's my code

```
import System
from System import Array

iData = Array.CreateInstance(System.Single, 1024)
qData = Array.CreateInstance(System.Single, 1024)

import csv
with open(r'c:\test.csv', 'w') as fp:
writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
for i in range(0, 1024):
    val = repr(iData[i]) + repr(qData[i])
    writer.writerow(val)
print("done")
```

the above code works fine, but when I open `test.csv` file I see the following
[`EXCEL`]

[image]

[`NotePad++`]

[image]

but what I want to achieve is this (iData[i],qData[i]),

[image]

any suggestions please?

Comment: What does Excel think is the delimiter?

Comment: @LutzHorn, If I'm not wrong. Excel recognizes CSV files with delimiter (,)

Comment: Please include the exact content of `test.csv`.

Comment: The picture shown above is what I see, I had to crop due to higher number of rows(i.e 1024)

Comment: Please open `test.csv` in a plain text editor like Notepad++ and add the content (some lines are enough) to your question.

Comment: sorry, please see the edit? is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(0, 1024):
    writer.writerow([iData[i], qData[i]])
```